# Why doesn't most specialized template match in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xalan

This is my transformation:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <output>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="outer[@type='foo']/inner"/>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="outer[@type='foo']/inner[@type='bar1' or @type='bar2' or @type='bar3' or @type='bar4']">
        <item>
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="outer[@type='foo']/inner">
        <xsl:message terminate="yes">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('Unexpected type: ', @type)"/>
        </xsl:message>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

This is my input:

```
<root>
    <outer type="foo">
        <inner type="bar2">bar2</inner>
    </outer>
</root>
```

When I execute the transformation on the input, Xalan quits with a fatal error, which is caused by the `<xsl:message terminate="yes">` in the third `<xsl:template>`. Why? Shouldn't the second, more specialized `<xsl:template>` match instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution would be to simply have the 2 templates trade positions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <output>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="outer[@type='foo']/inner"/>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="outer[@type='foo']/inner">
        <xsl:message terminate="yes">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('Unexpected type: ', @type)"/>
        </xsl:message>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="outer[@type='foo']/inner[@type='bar1' or @type='bar2' or @type='bar3' or @type='bar4']">
        <item>
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Although this is probably not clean, so you should rather leave the order as it was and explicitly set a prio higher than .5 to the more specialized template instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <output>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="outer[@type='foo']/inner"/>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="outer[@type='foo']/inner[@type='bar1' or @type='bar2' or @type='bar3' or @type='bar4']" priority="1">
        <item>
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="outer[@type='foo']/inner">
        <xsl:message terminate="yes">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('Unexpected type: ', @type)"/>
        </xsl:message>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Explicitly setting the priority seems to be the cleanest fix, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Both of your matching expressions have a priority of .5 according to http://lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works/#priority

So your templates are conflicting. How about handling everything in 1 single template?

```
<xsl:template match="outer[@type='foo']/inner">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@type='bar1' or @type='bar2' or @type='bar3' or @type='bar4'">
            <item>
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            </item>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:message terminate="yes">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('Unexpected type: ', @type)"/>
            </xsl:message>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Found some more in the article I referenced above: "It is an error if there is more than one template rule left. If that happens, the XSLT processor can either signal the error or recover by invoking the matching template rule that occurs last in the stylesheet. Most processors will at least give a warning if this happens." So your XSLT processor (mine too, BTW!) belongs to those that don't give a warning and simply use the *last* matching template in the file.

Comment: It's definitely best to use explicit priorities. If you don't, then both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 say this is an error, which the processor can either report, or recover from by selecting the rule that comes last. XSLT 3.0 makes the "last rule wins" behaviour mandatory unless you specify `<xsl:mode on-multiple-match="fail"/>`